# GET request to obtain page's content

Tags: c, networking, winsock, get-request

I am trying to perform the C equivalent of the python's:
`requests.get('http://test.com')`

I am first using `getaddrinfo()` to resolve the hostname (it has 4 ips) to `ip` then `server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);` and it connects successfully (doesn't give an error). But when I try to display the page by sending `"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n` request, it basically returns 404 error (page not found) content. Here is the function:

---

```
void foo ()
{
    struct addrinfo     hints;
    struct addrinfo     *result = NULL;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol   = IPPROTO_TCP;

    char host[256], port [256];
    strcpy(host, "www.test.com");
    strcpy(port, "80");
    getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &result);

    struct sockaddr_in  *sockaddr_ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)result->ai_addr;
    char ip [256];
    strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(sockaddr_ipv4->sin_addr));

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 );
    char *message , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }
    message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }
    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    puts(server_reply);*/
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

---

Result

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Date: Fri, 15 Sep 2017 03:19:41 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Server: ghs Content-Length:
>   1561 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>
> Error 404 (Not Found)!!1
>   
>       *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{backgrou
>   nd:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto
>   0;max-width:390px;min-height :180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* >
>   body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/error s/robot.png) 100%
>   5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflo
>   w:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media
>   screen and (m
>   ax-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0
>   }}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo
>   _color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-reso
>   lution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/
>   2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100%
>   100%;-moz-border-image:ur
>   l(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png)
>   0}}@media only screen and
>   (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:ur
>   l(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png)
>   no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100%
>   100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:5 4px;width:150px}
>
> **404.** Thata?Ts an error.
>
> The requested URL
>   `/` was not found on this server.  Thata? Ts all we
>   know.

---

What am I doing wrong? How must I approach this?

Comment: Please post code, there is no sufficient information in your post to know *what's wrong?*, also why are you trying this? Can't you use a library like [*libcurl*](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)?

Comment: You are right I should've. Updated. Also my project is heavily windows and winsock based. And if I can't do that with those.. I can then try other APIs.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with python... The tag is misleading.

Comment: Also, please post the EXACT output. You did not answer why not use something like *libcurl*. Although I don't think it's easy to use libcurl on windows there are alternatives for sure. A http client is a complex monster, so if you need some features like the ones you claim to support when you say `"HTTP/1.1"` you should use a library.

Comment: Check [this library that I wrote](https://github.com/iharob/libhttpio), specially for the ability to write websocket clients. If you need help please contact me and I will try to help.

Comment: @Addison when the question is about C version of Python thing won't it make sense to tag both?

Comment: Don't spam tags. Just because you know Pathon does not justify the Python tag!

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Only how to do what I am trying to achieve with it.

Comment: @Olaf I don't know python at all. But as far as I noticed, it has a very easy straightforward way of doing what I want, which appears to be much more complex in C and winsock

Comment: @Edenia: A good, grilled steak with a red, bloody center is a delicious meal. Add a baked potatoe and it is perfect. Hmm … we do post unrelated sentences, don't we?

Comment: Your socket is getting connected and server is replying, it replies error 404, may be it does not want to serve request for /, do you get a page from browser for http://test.com/

Comment: @Pras Yes, I do. Also test.com It is a website intended to embed its output to source codes, though it shows python, ruby and other irrelevant language examples

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within HTTP/1.1 you need to specify a `Host` header.  Within HTTP/1.0 you do not.  Therefore, you must either change this to be:

```
 GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n
```

or

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
 Host: the.hostname.com\r\n\r\n
```

This change was made since virtual hostnames had become so prevalent.